# Starting Xamarin foreground service sample crashes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm looking to create a Xamarin foreground service and thought taking the sample from https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/ApplicationFundamentals/ServiceSamples/ForegroundServiceDemo would be a good first step.
After building and deploying to my Samsung S10 it just crashes when clicking 'Start Service'.

The line it fails on is TimeStampService.cs line 155, on the code:

```
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
```

With null reference exception. The stack trace:

```
at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception (System.Exception e) [0x0000e] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12 
at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLII_I (_JniMarshal_PPLII_I callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0, System.Int32 p1, System.Int32 p2) [0x00022] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:221 at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLII_I(intptr,intptr,intptr,int,int)
```

I've tried a few things, including updating to latest versions of references, but still nothing I do fixes this.
I tried creating a new background service from scratch and still get the same error.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the foreground service permission in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Such as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

**Update**
You can try to use the code in my old answer:[Trouble getting local notifications to fire in Android when the application is closed (using AlarmManager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462702/trouble-getting-local-notifications-to-fire-in-android-when-the-application-is-c/71464360#71464360)

In addition, start it in the mainactivity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ForgroundServiceDemo));
 StartForegroundService(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I've just tried it but doesn't fix the issue. Still get the same error in the same place

Comment: I tried to test the demo but failed, because the code is too old. You can check foreground service code in the link in the update answer.@Hallupa

Comment: Thanks - just tried that but still same issue :(
It's disappointing that Xaramin's own samples don't even work - it seems Xamarin isn't really ready for using in production code
I'm thinking now to switch to React Native to see if I get the same issue

Comment: What's the android version of yours? @Hallupa

Comment: I'm using Android 12

Comment: I've also add a bug report in the Xamarin sample project Github - hopefully they will fix it: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/issues/335

Comment: For the android 12, you need to declare the exported's value of the service such as `[Service (Exported = false)]`. @Hallupa

Comment: Just tried adding [Service(Exported = false)] to the service - still no luck! Same error as before :(

Comment: Had you tried to test it on a simulator?@Hallupa

Comment: Just tested the emulator using API 30 (Android 11), 31 (Android 12) and 32 (Android 12.1). All 3 give the same exception with the original sample code and also with your suggestions above

Comment: I also just tried updating to the latest version of Visual Studio and updating the sample project's nuget references to the latest version, but still get the exception

Comment: Did you try to delete the line caused the null exception and the code about the pending intent?@Hallupa